# Multiple Repositories in build.gradle is not working (jzy3d) (MultiModuleProject)

Tags: java, gradle, jzy3d

I've got a problem with my Java project in gradle. I'm using several dependencies with gradle, one of it is the jzy3d.api. I have included it in the build.gradle file and added the url to the repositories but it doesn't find it. I've added the repository for it as it is located here: http://maven.jzy3d.org/releases/org/jzy3d/jzy3d-api/1.0.2/
But the Error Message seems like that it isn't searching there. Can please someone tell me why?
Here is my build.gradle and the Error Message:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'    // optional, for IntelliJ IDEA project
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.jzy3d.org/releases"
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.6.0'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-math3', version: '3.6.1'
    compile group: 'org.jzy3d', name: 'jzy3d-api', version: '1.0.2'
    compile group: 'org.jfree', name: 'jfreechart', version: '1.5.0'
}
```

```
Execution failed for task ':BusinessLayer:compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':BusinessLayer:compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.jzy3d:jzy3d-api:1.0.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jzy3d/jzy3d-api/1.0.2/jzy3d-api-1.0.2.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :BusinessLayer > project :DataLayer

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

When I'm adding something to the url, for example `url "https://maven.jzy3d.org/releases/maven2"` the Error Message says:

```
Could not find org.jzy3d:jzy3d-api:1.0.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://maven.jzy3d.org/releases/maven2/org/jzy3d/jzy3d-api/1.0.2/jzy3d-api-1.0.2.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jzy3d/jzy3d-api/1.0.2/jzy3d-api-1.0.2.pom
```

So I think that for some reason it don't want to search in the `https://maven.jzy3d.org/releases` directory...

Comment: I doubt the issue is about "multiple repositories", it probably is about the jz3d repository. Just to rule that out, have you tried using `http` instead of `https` in your repository declaration?

Comment: I think I got it now: I had to add the repository url also to the other modules an their build.gradle files. Thanks anyways!

Comment: please spell out the fix? @MrPchicken ?